# Import table from txt file with specific rows

Tags: import

I have a .txt file written as

1 2

3 4

5 6

7 8

9 10

11 12

I would like to import it as three matrices according to the rows.

I used 
b = Import["d:\am.txt", {"Table", Range[1, 2]}]

Seems it does not work, "Data" will be normal terminated, but not in the form of matrix.. Is there any solution for importing data in the format of table by specifying rows?

Comment: A suggestion: look at `Skip` and `Read`.  Read as strings and convert with `ImportString` or related functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just rename `"Table"` to `"Data"`

```
Import["am.txt", {"Data", {1, 2}}]
(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} *)
```

P.S. delete empty lines in the text file if you have them

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is stored in "matrix.txt", you can do the following:

```
m = Import["matrix.txt"];

temp = Partition[StringSplit[m], 4];
```

and finally form the matrices:

```
Partition[#, {2}] & /@ temp
```

This does the structure, maybe some type conversations are still necessary.